# An IMO $1986$ sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, contest-math

I have been stuck on this problem for some time, but I don't have any idea as to where to start. The problem is as follows:

Let $(a_{n\in \mathbb N})$ be the sequence of integers defined recursively by $$a_0 =0, a_1 =1, a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1} +a_n$$ Find the common divisors of $a_{1986}$ and $a_{6891}$.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What goes wrong if you try to apply the same argument used to get the gcd of fibonacci numbers, eg [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/FibonacciGCD.shtml)?

Comment: Following the arguments in @lulu's link, it appears that the sequence in this problem satisfies the same relation (gcd of $F_m$ and $F_n$ is $F_{gcd(m,n)}$). So the problem should amount to finding the GCD of 1986 and 6891, which is hopefully a small enough number that the corresponding term in the sequence can be found by hand.

Comment: @Semiclassical I found out the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think the solutions of IMO problems are available on other sites

Comment: I think you must mention that this is a long list question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can show inductively that $(u_n,u_{n+1})=1$ and
$$
u_{m}=u_{k}u_{m-k+1}+u_{k-1}u_{m-k},\tag{1}
$$
whenever $\,k,m\in\mathbb N$ and $k< m$.

Suppose now that (Euclidean division)
$$
m=\ell k+\upsilon, \quad \upsilon\in\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\},
$$
then it is readily shown, a consequence of $(1)$ that
$$
(u_m,u_k)=(u_k,u_\upsilon). \tag{2}
$$

Using $(2)$ repeatedly we obtain that
$$
(u_m,u_k)=u_{(m,k)},
$$
and as $(6891,1986)=3$, then
$$
(u_{6891},u_{1986})=u_3=4.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Just a Hint to start:**

The characteristic equation is
$$x^2-4x-1=0$$ 
the roots are
$$r_1=2+\sqrt{5} \;\;r_2=2-\sqrt{5}$$

thus

$$a_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$$
with
$a_0=A+B=0$ and $Ar_1+Br_2=1$

$\implies A=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}=-B$.

Comment: And then what? You find the common divisors of $Ar_1^{1986}-Ar_2^{1986}$ and $Ar_1^{6981}-Ar_2^{6981}$. It is not the most convenient way, if possible at all.

Comment: @marwalix It is the only way to compute $a_1986$

Comment: But you do not need to compute the two numbers to know their divisors as in the comment by @lulu

Comment: A convenient representation for the given boundary conditions is $a_n=\dfrac{r_1^n-r_2^n}{r_1-r_2}$. This will factorize for any given $n$, yielding $$a_n=r_1^{n-1}+r_1^{n-2}r_2+\cdots+r_1r_2^{n-2}+r_2^{n-1}.$$ (Don't know where to go from there, alas...)

Comment: @marwalix because $A=-B$ and $\gcd(1986, 6981)=3$ it is not too far (instead of "easy") to see that $\gcd(a_{1986},  a_{6891})=a_3$.